# How to clone Github to React Native Project

Tags: reactjs, git, react-native

Im trying to clone github code (https://github.com/philnash/react-express-starter) to my react native project. However, When I run the command `git clone https://github.com/philnash/react-express-starter.git` in the terminal, I get the following error

```
git : The term 'git' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.At line:1 char:1

+ git clone {https://github.com/philnash/react-express-starter.git}
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`
```

I am pretty new to this and Im not sure why. Your help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure git is installed:

**git --version**

If git isn't installed that should give you an option to install it or visit https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: I just installed git through the link. Using the git CMD, when I run the command "git --version" I'm able to see the version. However, in react native (VS code) terminal I'm still unable to see the version nor download the package.

Comment: Use your OS's terminal to clone the repo( mac: terminal, windows: command prompt), then you should be able to open and access the directory inside vs code when it's cloned to your local machine.